# IIS 6 Application mapping default settings

Tags: .net, asp.net, sharepoint, iis, iis-6

This is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246624/sharepoint-multiple-document-upload-http-post-verb-not-allowed/1271132#1271132) I asked last week, but the current issue is more IIS-centric.

As a workaround to correct the issue, I removed the wildcard mapping for the web application (which was set to `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll`)

I would like to be able to add back this wildcard setting (as there might be side effects to removing this) -- but **exclude** the *.dll extension from being mapped to the ASP.NET endpoint.

How might I go about doing this in **IIS6**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My gut feeling tells me you should write an HttpModule, that filters out .dll requests, so still have the "catch-all" wild card mapping, but any request for dll's (and .config) are filtered out by the httpmodule...

Another option is to explicitly set the file types you do want handled by ASP.NET, wouldn't be to big a list I imagine, js, html, the usual suspects...